# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el resultado de una variable después de una función?

Tags: python, funciones, variables, condiciones, memoria

Estoy escribiendo un código para evaluar triángulos, el tipo de triangulo y área en base a 3 lados.
Me he topado con el problema de que mi variable se vuelve "none" al terminar la función. Me he percatado de que mientras se está ejecutando esa función el valor si se queda guardado, pero después de que cambio a otra función el valor se borra.

He hecho un ejemplo pequeño de mi problema:

```
def prueba1():
    Variable1 = str(input("Sólo escribe Y: "))
    if Variable1 in "Y":
        print("Si")
        print(Variable1)

prueba1()

print(Variable1)
```

En el primer `print(Variable1)` funciona, pero el segundo no (el que está fuera de la función).

Sé que me estaré saltando algo básico, pero apenas estoy aprendiendo a programar así que agradezco mucho su ayuda :)

Comment: Las variables son locales a la función; no existen fuera de ella.

Comment: También puedes estudiar la materia por tu cuenta. Un buen punto de partida es el [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) oficial.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya comentó Candid, las variables "nacen" y "mueren" al interno de las funciones. A continuación te proporciono algunos ejemplos con sus explicaciones de modo que puedas comprender mejor como usarlas.

La siguiente función incrementa de 1 el valor de la variable pasada como parámetro en su ejecución. Como puedes ver tras su ejecución, el resultado se guarda en la variable `resultado`, esto se logra con el `return` al interno de la función el cual devuelve el número incrementado. Y esta es la forma de acceder a las variables de una función. Todo lo que devolvamos de una función por medio de `return` sobrevive a la función si lo guardamos en una variable como la `resultado` en mi ejemplo, esto vale también para variables, listas, etc que hayan sido creadas completamente al interno de la función como el input en tu ejemplo.

```
a=1

def incrementar(valor):
    valor+=1
    return valor

resultado = incrementar(a)

print(resultado)

>> 2
```

Formas de hacer que una función afecte a las variables que se encuentran fuera de ella. En este ejemplo hablaremos de las variables globales, este tipo de variables pueden ser accedidas desde cualquier lugar del código para modificar su valor. El siguiente código suma dos números y guarda el resultado dentro de la variable externa `a`, pero la variable `b` muere al terminar la función.

```
a = 1

def suma():
    global a
    b = 2
    a = a + b

print(a)

>> 3
```

El siguiente ejemplo hace lo mismo que el anterior pero sin utilizar variables globales.

```
a = 1

def suma():
    b = 2
    return a = a + b

a = suma(a)

print(a)

>> 3
```

Este último ejemplo es siempre mejor que el precedente. Es considerado una mala practica utilizar variables globales, debe reservarse solo para esos pocos casos en los que es imprescindible emplearlas.